# Integrate JWT with file_get_contents

Tags: php, api, endpoint

I have a small endpoint, for receiving data via POST.

How could I integrate JWT with file_get_content?

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $object = json_decode($json);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        die(header('HTTP/1.0 415 Unsupported Media Type'));
    }
    file_put_contents('callback.test.txt', print_r($object, true));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to implement JWT authentication on top of this endpoint?